# How to get each step logged in Pentaho 8.0

Tags: pentaho

How can I get details for each step in each transformation inside a job logged separately so I can check the step runtime ??? I would like to get the steps ordered but it would perfectly fit me if I can get only datetimestamp for each record that is written inside the database.... but the problem is, that it runs in parallel and writes all data at one run only !! which means all steps have the same datetime ... is there any way how to achieve it? Because otherwise, I am not able to determine any bottlenecks, performance problems, etc .... this really sucks

Answer (score 0):

On the transformation properties, every transformation has a "Logging" tab where you can specify a DB connection to store the logging data/metadata, as well as the fields you want to save.

Regarding the timestamp associated to the execution time, yes, transformation steps run in parallel and that's the way a transformation is designed to work; you can alter that behavior by placing blocking steps, but that will result in performance loss.